# How to process results fetched from cache and network using AWS AppSync for Android

Tags: android, caching, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using AWS AppSync for Android, and I want to display a list of `Persons` into a `RecyclerView`. I am fetching paginated data with the `AppSyncResponseFetchers.CACHE_AND_NETWORK` flag. If data is present in the cache, `onResponse` is called twice, causing data duplication in the RecyclerView.

What is the right way to combine data returned by these 2 calls?

```
private void loadNextPersons() {
    AWSAppSyncClient client = AppSyncClientFactory.getAppSyncClient(AppSyncAuthMode.KEY);
    client.query(AllPersonsByCityQuery.builder()
             .city(cityName)
             .limit(10)
             .nextToken(nextToken)
             .build())
           .responseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.CACHE_AND_NETWORK).enqueue(loadCallback);
}

private GraphQLCall.Callback<AllPersonsByCityQuery.Data> loadCallback= new GraphQLCall.Callback<AllPersonsByCityQuery.Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<AllPersonsByCityQuery.Data> response) {
        // Called twice if we have data in the cache and network connection
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            adapter.addData(response.data().allPersonsByCity().persons());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the responseFetcher() method, why are u giving it Network and cache params?

Comment: @Jason, because I want to get fast results from cache first even if they are stale and then update them with the latest data from server

Comment: Then you just separate the methods. Do the cache call before the Network call

Comment: .... don't `>>>add<<<Data`, just replace with new set

Comment: @xadm, yeah I found out that ```response``` contains fromCache() which returns true or false. It means that I should write bulky logic based on fromCache() and another boolean variable in onResponse(). Is there a neater way?

Comment: what it can change if you still will be **add**ing results?? use other method of useining results, universal for both responses/calls